# Can my domain with subfolder to connect to EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, https

My plan is to add HTTPS and SSL to EC2. What I have a problem is that I have my own domain, websites and SSL certificate all on different hosting like Lunarpages. Is there a possible for me to allow my domain like this https://www.example.com/apps/project3/api to connect to EC2 from Lunarpages even though I have already SSL certificate installed on Lunarpages hosting. So I don't need to create SSL certificate on EC2. I don't want to move my websites with www.example.com to EC2, it should remain with Lunarpages hosting.

Is there an option I can connect from my  https://www.example.com/apps/project3/api (not subdomain) and SSL certificate from other hosting to EC2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### TL;DR

Use Lunarpages as a [reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy).

### About DNS

DNS can not manage "subfolders" (URI). When the user is typing your URL in your website (or when you make a request to your API), the web browser will do a DNS resolution of the domain. Therefore, it will connect to `www.example.com` and then search for `/apps/project3/api`. It means it is not possible to have `www.example.com/a` on one server and `www.example.com/b` on an other one by using a DNS mechanism.

### Reverse proxy

To solve this problem, one solution is the reverse proxy. If Lunarpages allows it, you can use their hosting as a proxy to your EC2. Every request of `www.example.com` will be processed on Lunarpages. Only the requests of `/apps/project3/api/*` will be proxied to EC2. Lunarpages will do the SSL termination and then proxy the request to EC2.

### Drawbacks

As you can imagine, having the request going to Lunarpages then to the EC2 and finally going back to the client throught Lunarpages can have a big impact on performance and response time.

The security is also important because the communication between Lunarpages and the EC2 should be encrypted. It means another SSL certificate ([self signed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-signed_certificate)) should be present on the EC2.

### Other solutions

I strongly recommand to use the same hosting provider for the same domain name even if there is multiple servers to process the requests. Tree solutions comes to mind:

- Host everything on Lunarpages
- Host everything on AWS (reconsider this option)
- Use a different subdomain for the API (`api.example.com`) that will point to the EC2 and manage the SSL certificate of `api.example.com` on this EC2.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I have a quick question to ask you. Even I have SSL certificate already installed on Lunarpages for www.example.com. Do I create a different SSL certificate for api.example.com (subdomain) that will point to the EC2?

Comment: It is recommanded to not have wildcard certificate (`*.example.com`) but to have specific certificates for each subdomain. Whether the traffic is proxied from Lunarpages or not, there should be a SSL certificated on the EC2 instance.

Comment: Thank you for the info. Could you please tell me why you don't recommended to not have wildcard certificate? Which SSL certificate is the best one to have? I looked at Comodo and GoDaddy.

Comment: If you need a DV (Domain Validated) certificate then Let's Encrypt should be the tool to use. DV certficates are enough for most use cases. If you need a stronger certificate then GoDaddy is a good company.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the info!

Comment: I my answer was good enough, don't hesitate to [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).